# asp-validation-summary blocking back button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-core

I have a page with a form doing validation on the model.  The problem is its blocking the cancel button.

When the user clicks the cancel button its forcing them to supply a new password and confirm it.  It should just send them back to the previous page.

```
@model Auth.Controllers.Account.RecoverPasswordViewModel

<div class="mdl-typography--text-center">
    <h2 class="mdl-typography--headline">Gendan kodeord</h2>
    <p class="mdl-typography--body-1">Gendand kodeord til din konto</p>
</div>

<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="mdl-color-text--red-400"></div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("RecoverPassword", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "form-horizontal", role = "form"})) {
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Code" />
    <fieldset>
        <div class="mdl-textfield  mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
            <input class="mdl-textfield__input" asp-for="NewPassword" type="password" autocomplete="off" required autofocus/>
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" asp-for="NewPassword">Nyt kodeord</label>
            <span asp-validation-for="NewPassword" class="mdl-textfield__error"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-textfield  mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
            <input class="mdl-textfield__input" asp-for="ConfirmNewPassword" type="password" autocomplete="off" required/>
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" asp-for="ConfirmNewPassword">Bekræft nyt kodeord</label>
            <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmNewPassword" class="mdl-textfield__error"></span>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="ReturnUrl" value="@Model.ReturnUrl" />
        </div>

        <div class="actions">
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--primary" onclick="window.history.back()" causesvalidation="false">Gå tilbage</button>
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--primary mdl-button--raised mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">Gem</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

I tried adding causesvalidation="false" on the go back button but it didnt help.  Is there a way to force it to only validate on the save button?

Comment: The back button problem can be solved by implementing the data request in a different way. The first way would be to send a HTTP GET request, instead of a HTTP POST. Request parameters, if any, are sent in the URL and the back button will then work without problems. Source -> https://damienbod.com/2018/06/15/asp-net-core-mvc-form-requests-and-the-browser-back-button/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `windows.history.back()`, use redirect (`RedirectToAction` and the like).

`windows.history.back()` will trigger the previous request to be resent (if you came there from a post request) which is undesired behavior.

Instead create a link

```
<a class="mdl-button mdl-button--primary mdl-button--raised mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect"
    asp-controller="MyController" asp-action="Index">Back</a>
```

Comment: yeah but thats a link not a button its going to look diffrent wont it?

Comment: With the proper styles it should look same, i.e. `class="mdl-button mdl-button--primary mdl-button--raised mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect"` since these are what determines how it looks. Material styles are not limited to the element type (i.e. button). Generally buttons trigger forms and are more declarative, links don't.